# How do I get started with Cordova

Tags: cordova

Are there any good tutorials or books to get started with Cordova?

I have already visited the official website but I didn't think the documentation they have is a good starting point.

Comment: https://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/

Comment: It may be that things have progressed since I worked in it, but I found learning jQuery Mobile to be a great addition to working with Cordova.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to choose a framework for hybrid mobile development.

I use [`ionic`](http://ionicframework.com/) framework, which has a lot of powerful components and tools.

Also `ionic` is built on the top of the **AngularJS**. In addition, there are a lot of good examples and tutorials  for ionic development. See [devdactic blog](https://devdactic.com/devblog/) for some really good tutorials. Also [Nic Raboy's](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLII40EOBF0-saXmyzsA9YGSL5QWKQctGu) video tutorials in youtube about both ionic and **Cordova**.

Comment: I never heard of ionic framework before but as long as it's built on top of the AngularJS then I'm sold on it. Thanks!

Comment: @ZainHatim yes, give it a try, It's awesome. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I´m not completely sure that this is the right forum for you but start out with the following:

1. [Get started fast by Apache Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted)
2. Take a look at NetBeans [Getting Started with Cordova Applications](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/webclient/cordova-gettingstarted.html)
3. Take a look at this [Apache Cordova Tutorial](https://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/)

The last link will give you a great look and tutorial of

- How to create and build (compile and package) a Cordova project using the CLI (Command Line Interface).
- How to use different data storage strategies.
- How to use several Cordova APIs such as Geolocation, Contacts, and Camera.
- How to handle specific mobile challenges such as touch events, scrolling, styling, page transitions, etc.
- How to build an application using a single-page architecture and HTML templates.

Answer (score 0):

As vahid najafi, I recommend you to use a Framework, there is other good framework for mobile applications called Lugo, http://lungo.tapquo.com/